# php json formatting string to specific parameters for coding in android and apple environments

Tags: php, json

I have a json string which is built like so

```
    $response = array();

   $response['success'] = true;
    $response['paymentRequired'] = true;
    $response['url'] =       'http://somefancyweburl.co.uk/members/index.php';

     echo urldecode(stripslashes(json_encode($response)));
```

Works great and is outputting

```
  {"success":true,"paymentRequired":false,"url":"http://somefancyurl.co.uk/members/index.php"}
```

My app developer has asked for it in this format....

```
 {"data"[{"success":true,"paymentRequired":false,"url":"http://somefancyurl.co.uk/members/index.php"}]}
```

I cant figure out how to create my array in such a way.

Things I have tried......
calling the array as

```
 $response = array('data')
```

searching everywhere online.  Can't find out how its done.  Can someone help me please? Many thanks

Comment: it should be `$result = array('data' => array($response));` like in answer I wrote below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$response = array();
$response['success'] = true;
$response['paymentRequired'] = true;
$response['url'] =       'http://somefancyweburl.co.uk/members/index.php';

$array = array('data' => array($response));

echo urldecode(stripslashes(json_encode($array)));
```

this is version with the data inside [ ]

Answer (score 0):

```
    $response = array();

        $response['success'] = true;

        $response['paymentRequired'] = true;

        $response['url'] =       'http://somefancyweburl.co.uk/members/index.php';

    **$rArray = array('data' => array($response));**

echo urldecode(stripslashes(json_encode($rArray)));
```

Here you need to add additional array key 'data' and another array for response.